# how to associate columns between differnt tables

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, design-pattern

So i'm designing a database for my application which is basically a qustionaire. I designed my db as best as i could and i think it kinda works.

The questionair isn't straightfoward. by this i mean there are multiple questionairs and the questions are not a simple (yes/no). some questions are multiple choice (lists) some are a yes/no (enum) and for some qusetions i have a other 'option' in which users can input string.

Here are some questions which i think illustrate the returned data types:

q1) do you like cats?

- yes
- no

q2) pick toppings on your burger?

- onions
- tomatoes
- cheese
- pickles

q3) what is your favourite number?

- one
- two
- three
- other    [ ' enter your favourite number ' ]

**What i am trying to figure out**

How can i associate questions with their possible "options"?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While a better solution might exist, a simple way would be to have a `Questions` table with `QuestionId` as the primary key, `QuestionText` column, and an `QuestionType` column so your consuming application can render the appropriate control (e.g. Q1 likely should be a radio button vs Q2 which would be a checkbox).

And have an `Answers` table with an `AnswerId` primary key column, the `QuestionId` it belongs to as a foreign key reference, and an `AnswerText` column so it can hold any data type of answer. It may be helpful to also have a column called `AnswerDataType` so you can dynamically cast the `AnswerText` to the underlying data type when needed.